# Пустая ячейка во flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть обычный flebox с элементами:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 2.5px;
}
.flexbox__item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2.5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item offset-1"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
</div>
```

Как вставить в этот flexbox пустую ячейку после offset не использую дополнительной разметки и after с before?

Т.е. нужно, чтобы вышло вот так, но без указания ширины у блоков. Только flex-grow

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 2.5px;
}
.flexbox__item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2.5px;
  width: 25%;
}

.offset-1 {
  margin-right: calc(25% + 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item offset-1"></div>
  <div class="flexbox__item"></div>
</div>
```

Количество ячеек неизвестно. `Offset-1` означает, что нужно сделать пустую одну ячейку, `offset-2` - две и т. д.

Comment: Ну если честно, то только JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с дополнительными обертками - расти будут обертки, а элементы-ячейки внутри растущих оберток будут занимать 1/2, 1/3 и т. д. ширины оберток.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}

.flexbox__item {
  margin: 3px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flexbox__item-inner {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.offset-1 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.offset-1 .flexbox__item-inner {
  width: 50%;
}

.offset-2 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.offset-2 .flexbox__item-inner {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox__item offset-1">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox__item">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexbox__item">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox__item offset-2">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox__item">
    <div class="flexbox__item-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отличная идея. Жалко что мне не подойдёт :) Но главное, что проблему решает

Comment: А чо не подойдет?

Comment: Та элемент один должен быть, т.е. без элемент в элементе